# Python pickle index out of range

Tags: python, windows, macos, sockets, pickle

I'm getting the following error when i try to run my py file on a windows machine, everything works fine from the Mac, but i cant get the two machines to talk to one another. do i have to 'dumps' in ascii; if so how do i do that? any suggestions? THANKS!!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Keith\Desktop\rcserver\tcpserver_simpleReceive.py", line 23, in <module>
new_data = pickle.loads(data)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1382, in loads
return Unpickler(file).load()
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
dispatch[key](self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1165, in load_put
self.memo[self.readline()[:-1]] = self.stack[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The dumps:

```
if e.type == pygame.JOYAXISMOTION:
    client_socket.sendall (pickle.dumps(e.dict,0))
```

this is the loads:

```
 data = client_socket.recv(1024)
new_data = pickle.loads(data)
```

Comment: Why are you using negative index in a list `stack[-1]` ?

Comment: Are you reading or writing the file in binary mode. The newline may be an issue here. Just show us, how you are dumping and loading the file.

Comment: @ATOzTOA: Why not? Also, it's not "him", it's the `pickle` module that's doing it.

Comment: @TimPietzcker New to me :)

Comment: @ATOzTOA: negative indexes are subtracted from the length of the sequence; they count from the end. `seq[-1]` is the last item, `seq[-2]` is the second last. They can be used in slices too: `seq[:-1]` means 'everything except the last entry'.

Comment: Interesting let me get the code check above

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7 on the Mac, too?

Comment: 2.6.6 is running on the mac. On the PC the code runs fine until the socket connection is accepted then the loads error happens...

Comment: Actually, according to the code you've posted, you already are doing your `dumps` in ASCII. Have you tried using protocol -1 instead of 0? (I wouldn't expect this to make a difference over a socket, but it is worth trying, just to see.)

Comment: @JohnY isnt -1 reserved for older versions of Python? I did give it a try and it gave an `EOFERROR`

Comment: @rcpilotp51: Protocol -1 means use the newest available. 0 is for maximum backward compatibility. Python 2.6 and 2.7 are (in principle) fully pickle-compatible.

Comment: @JohnY that is why im totally baffled. Why is it so stubborn when i run the same script on a pc...there is nothing complicated going on.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the data you are trying to send is what you expected to be sent; and that the data you are receiving is the data you expected to be received?  Check the length of the dumped string and the length of the received data.  Print them to see if there are obvious differences.  Dump to a file and transfer to the receiving machine using USB drive or e-mailing it to yourself to see if you can unpickle the file.  Etc.  Basic debugging.

Comment: @JohnY everything is what it should be. I sent it to and from the same computer over a socket connection. printed it out and it dumped and loaded just fine.

Comment: You already said it works from one computer to the same computer. The point is to see whether the data is getting to the other computer; and if it *is* getting there *correctly*, then seeing whether `pickle` on the second computer can indeed unpickle data generated on the first computer.

Comment: @JohnY I'm going to be testing this today. Meanwhile, Is there a way to have the program ignore errors and keep retrying until a connection is made? When I run the program I get random errors about information received, but if I restart the program; it works fine... can I loop the script until it "works fine?"

Comment: @JohnY I'm revisiting this project. I've been spending the better part of the morning on this. Is there any other way to accomplish the same thing? "Hard code it" to work?

Comment: You haven't given any additional information. You need to verify (1) the receiving machine is receiving any data at all, (2) the data received is identical to the data sent, and (3) the data received can be unpickled. Which of those 3 steps have completed successfully?

Comment: @JohnY yes but how do i do that if its throwing an error?

Comment: Break things down into simpler steps. Take stuff out of your program until you stop getting errors. Really inspect the data on both ends. I already gave you some things to look into in my previous comments. If you don't understand basic debugging strategies, it's going to be very hard to help you. You need to be able to try things (with a purpose, not just randomly) and then report what happened.